# (Python) Connecting subprocess pipes/Running command through a jump box

Tags: python, command, subprocess

So I want to use python to run a command on a server, but to do that I have to go through another box. I connect to the first box by running ssh through subprocess. However, Im unsure how to then get into the second box and run commands through that subprocess object.

My subprocess statement:

```
command = "ssh servername"
sshConnection = subprocess.Popen(command.split(),stderr=subprocess.PIPE
                                  ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The only methods I can think of:

Somehow connect the pipes of two subprocess commands?
Establish a SSH tunnel first then run commands through that?
Any other ideas? Am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
cmd = "mycmd myarg1 myarg2"
ssh_command = "ssh servername %s" % cmd
sshConnection = subprocess.Popen(ssh_command.split(),stderr=subprocess.PIPE
                                  ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Of course you need to also shell-escape the command, if it contains special characters.

A slicker alternative, I personally like, is using [plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote.html#guide-remote-commands).  You can nest remote (ssh) commands.

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that I want to keep the SSH session open so I can continue to send commands. Im concerned about the resource usage of reestablishing a SSH session each time I want to run a command. Also, I cant use third party modules for this project :/

Answer (score 0):

If, by "go through another box", you mean "initiate an ssh connection from the jumpbox to the server", try:

```
command = "ssh jumpbox ssh servername /bin/ls -l"
sshConnection = subprocess.Popen(command.split(),stderr=subprocess.PIPE
                              ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Can I do this without closing the ssh connection after execution, and be able to keep sending command and grabbing output?

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing a lot of ssh with subprocess I suggest you should use [Fabric](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)